# How can I use rspec to test routes that are being rescued and redirected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, routes, bdd, rspec-rails

I was trying to write some quick routing tests for a simple api so I wrote:

```
  it "delete" do
    delete("/api/notifications/:id").should_not be_routable
  end
```

But I received:

```
Failure/Error: delete("/api/notifications/:id").should_not be_routable
     expected {:delete=>"/api/notifications/:id"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"application", :action=>"rescue404", :a=>"api/notifications/:id"}
```

I quickly realized I was rescuing from 404, so pretty much everything is routable.

```
  unless Rails.env.development?
    rescue_from NotFound, :with => :rescue404
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :rescue404
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :rescue404
  end

  def rescue404
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :text => 'Something went wrong. Record not found or url is incorrect.\n' }
      format.xml  { render :text => 'Something went wrong. Record not found or url is incorrect.\n' }
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, :alert => 'That page does not exist, sorry bro!' }
    end
  end
```

That leaves me with this for a test:

```
  it "delete" do
    delete("/api/notifications/:id").should route_to("application#rescue404", :a => "api/notifications/:id")
  end
```

Writing this way is error prone to me as I'm constantly getting the ':a =>' wrong. Is there any way I can test if an exception is being rescued?

This works:

```
  it "delete" do
    delete("/api/notifications/:id").should raise_error()
  end
```

...but what error should I be checking for? Or should I just leave it at that?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your rescues. Change:

```
unless Rails.env.development?
```

to:

```
if Rails.env.production?
```

That should leave the test env out of your rescue404 behavior.